# SplObjectStorage only maps by instances

Tags: php, arrays, object, dictionary, splobjectstorage

My problem is I want to map by object equality (==), not unique instances. In other words, refactor this to not throw an error and return the mapped value:

```
$var1 = (object) [1,2,10];
$var2 = (object) [1,2,10];
$objmap = new SplObjectStorage();
$objmap[$var1] = "mapped value here";
echo $objmap[$var2];
```

Edit: Also, if I end up needing to iterate over the keys of the SplObjectStorage object to get by equality, I'd like instead to know a good way to just hash objects/arrays and simply map to the hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement a hashing function for the object contents; something simple like this:

```
function getHash($obj)
{
    return md5(serialize($obj));
}

$objmap = array();
$objmap[getHash($var1)] = "mapped value here";
echo $objmap[getHash($var2)];
```

Comment: This is what I'm thinking, but I feel this is a tad expensive. I'm starting to figure I need to write my own `implode()` alternative...

Comment: It won't be expensive until you measure it :)